# Circular progress indicator not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show an `CircularProgressIndicator` whenever user presses on register button, here is my code:

```
onPressed: () async{
                if (_email.isNotEmpty && _password.isNotEmpty) {
                  startProgressIndicator();
                  FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                  UserCredential credential =  await mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
                  print(credential.user!.email);
                  //stopProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text(
                      "Please enter all information!",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    elevation: 5,
                    duration: Duration(
                      seconds: 3
                    ),
                    action: SnackBarAction(
                      label: "close",
                      onPressed: (){
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                      },
                    ),
                  ));
                }
```

`startProgressIndicator()`:

```
CircularProgressIndicator startProgressIndicator() {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      strokeWidth: 5,
    );
  }
```

`stopProgressIndicator()`:

```
CircularProgressIndicator stopProgressIndicator() {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: 0,
    );
  }
```

The loading icon doesn't appear at all.

All colors are correct(i.e. background color and progress bar color are different)

What is the issue here?

**EDIT**: I added the following code but it still isn't working:

```
Column(
  children: [
  <Other widgets>
  Visibility(
            visible: _isProgressVisible,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
  ]
)
```

and I set `_isProgressVisible` to `true` and false:

```
if (_email.isNotEmpty && _password.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isProgressVisible = true;
                  });
                  FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                  UserCredential credential =  await mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
                  print(credential.user!.email);
                  setState(() {
                    _isProgressVisible = false;
                  });
                }
```

Comment: Strange that answers have been given and you have not given any feedback to them. Not very motivating to answer your newer question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing the returned widget anywhere, `startProgressIndicator()` returns the widget but you're just calling not rendering it,
Either use like this

```
showCupertinoDialog(
      useRootNavigator: true,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return startProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
```

If you want to show that somewhere else you can do that like this

```
Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(children: [
        Visibility(
            visible: showIndicator,
            child: startProgressIndicator()),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('Here'),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => showIndicator = !showIndicator),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return startProgressIndicator();
```

That's just simple mistake
You have to return widget;